# Is there a way to redirect without changing url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, web

I want to redirect my users to

```
www.spredt.com/404
```

But still having the url look the same as they typed it in the first place.

For example is someone entered `www.spredt.com/93817218` and that page 
doesn't exist in my directory it will redirect them but it will change 
the url to `www.spredt.com/404`

I want the same `/93817218` to stay unchanged in the url but still redirect them to the error document 404.

Right now I'm handling redirection with the `.htaccess` file.

```
ErrorDocument 500 https://www.spredt.com/500
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.spredt.com/404
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.spredt.com/403
```

But this changes the url.

Comment: can you provide more details ? how are you serving your ressources?

Comment: Right now I'm doing it with .htaccess file. Just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you are redirecting your user in the 404 endpoint. 
But you can just return the 404 page template when they enter a false url, and not redirect them. 
The url will stay the same and they will see your 404 page.

I can't provide more detail because I don't have your code nor the langage.

**EDIT :**

In PHP you can do that to redirect and stay on the same URL :

```
include('http://www.spredt.com/404');
exit();
```

I can't test it right now, but it should work.

> Source :  https://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/545026-redirect-without-changing-address-your-browser

Comment: Just updated the question. I haven't done anything with the code. I have just handled redirection with the .htaccess file. It's a php website.

Comment: @FrancescoChiari I just edited my post with a PHP solution